# Getting started with cython on mac os

Tags: python, c++, xcode, macos, cython

I wrote a simple program in python:

```
// main.py
import re
links = re.findall('(https?://\S+)', 'http://google.pl http://youtube.com')
print(links)
```

Then I execute this:

```
cython main.py
```

It was generated a file: main.c
And then I tried this:

```
gcc main.c
```

And I have an error:

```
main.c:8:10: fatal error: 'pyconfig.h' file not found
#include "pyconfig.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

How to compile python to c ? How to get started with cython with xcode on mac ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to tell the `gcc` compiler where is the `pyconfig.h` file on your system using the `-I` flag. You can find it using the `find` program.

A **simpler way to compile** the module is using a `setup.py` module. Cython provides a `cythonize` function that starts this process for a `.pyx` module.

Another point you are missing is that **Cython files usually define helper functions to be used from a main Python module**.

Suppose you have the following setup as for dirs and files:

```
cython-start/
├── main.py
├── setup.py
└── split_urls.pyx
```

The contents of the `setup.py` are

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name="My first Cython app",
      ext_modules=cythonize('split_urls.pyx'),  # accepts a glob pattern
      )
```

The contents of the `split_urls.pyx` file are

```
import re

def do_split(links):
    return re.findall('(https?://\S+)', links)
```

And it is the `main.py` module which *uses the defined Cython function*:

```
import split_urls

URLS = 'http://google.pl http://youtube.com'
print split_urls.do_split(URLS)
```

Compile the Cython module by issuing:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Cythonizing split_urls.pyx
running build_ext
building 'split_urls' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7
... compiler output ...
```

And check that your main module is doing what it is supposed to do:

```
$ python main.py
['http://google.pl', 'http://youtube.com']
```

Comment: alternatively, you can just rename `main.py` to `main.pyx` and then create and run the `setup.py` as logc says. You can then do `import main` in the console or `python -c "import main"` in shell.